# Unmounting a external hard drive which has Ubuntu installed on it

Tags: dual-boot, unmount

I have Ubuntu installed on an external HDD drive.  The laptop has Windows installed before.

I started the computer, pressed F9, loaded Ubuntu, did a bit of basic programming, and then clicked turned off.  I turned on the computer again, and now it says that drive was not cleanly mounted.

So main question is: If you have Ubuntu installed on an external HDD drive, how do you cleanly unmount it?

Comment: If you `shutdown` your system using commands or gui 'shutdown' command & it completes its shutdown (and halts power if instructed) your system will be shutdown.  To unmount a drive, `umount` or click eject/power-off in your programs (eg, gnome-disks) but shutdown will cause this to occur if done & allowed to complete. I'm not sure what you mean by 'clicked turned off' sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to powering off your computer, you must properly shutdown your computer from the power menu, or you will potentially corrupt your file system (it's no longer clean).

Lets first check your file system for errors.

For 17.10 or lower...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For 18.04 or higher...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`